# Sorting integers in C with only basic math functions

Tags: c, sorting, integer-math

Im attempting to write a program in C

Given an input of three unique, non negative `int` type numbers, the program should sort them and output them sorted in an increasing order. For this program, only the basic mathematical constructs are permitted. (`+`,`-`,`/`,`*`,`%`)

Example of an input would be:

> Input three integer numbers:
>   32 29 21

And then, the example output should be:

> Sorted numbers: 21 29 31

The use of logical operators, like `>` `<` and `==` as well as selection statements `if` `for` and `switch` is explicitly not allowed.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate. Should have been closed as "unclear what you are asking" or "too broad" as it isn't clear what specific problem the OP has while implementing this.

Comment: I tried hammering this into something somewhat answerable. Let me know what you think and rollback as necessary.

Comment: @user3386109 I'll fix that now, I didn't intend to remove the "Unique"

Comment: @Magisch Thanks, I thought perhaps you knew something about the problem that I didn't. My bet is that there is no solution.

Comment: @user3386109 Oh, there is. The solution can be inferred out of nneo's answer to this.

Comment: @Magisch this is a spec

Comment: I'm not sure what this question is, apart from bad.

Comment: @Magisch mainly liked the answer he said in socvr. So let's move on.

Answer (score 8):

This is a bit tricky. With only "mathematical" arithmetic functions, I don't think it would be possible (i.e. using true mathematical operators on real numbers).

But, luckily, this is C and we have integer operations like integer divide. Integer division has the useful property that `a/b == 0` if `a<b` and `a/b > 0` if `a>b`. We can exploit this to write a `min` function that returns the smaller number from two you input:

```
unsigned math_min(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
    a++; b++; // ensure neither a nor b is zero
    unsigned c = ((a/b)*b + (b/a)*a) / ((a/b) + (b/a));
    return c-1; // correct for earlier increment
}
```

This works by computing `a/b*b` and `b/a*a`. If we assume `a` and `b` are distinct from each other and positive, then exactly one of these will be nonzero - the one corresponding to the smaller value. (In fact, this function works even if `a==b` since in that case we add `a+b` and divide by two).

Using this "math-only" `min` function, you should be able to implement a sorting operation; this is left as an exercise.

Comment: Nice - even though It does quite ensure neither a nor b is zero. (`a == UINT_MAX`)

Comment: Yes, using the idea from this min function, a max function based on it is indeed possible.  Whilst not too broad, posting an answer is probably spoiling someone's course assignment so I refrained from posting code.  Dealing with integer overflow handling is unrealistic without conditionals, values within a range seems a reasonable assumption to me for an artificially constrained example program.